# Displaying large amounts of data to be visible from a distance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in a specific situation that I could not find an answer to by searching here.  I am a .net developer just getting my feet wet with asp/html/css/javascript. I haven't done too much actual training with them, I am simply trying things out with a template called "Flat" to guide me.

I work for a medical billing company and was tasked with creating a few web pages for productivity for our billing departments.  These web pages are displayed on 60" TV's throughout the building so that employees can look up and see how they are doing.  The pages not only contain a good amount of data, but it also must be displayed so that someone can see it from their desk.  Within reason of course.

I have thrown something together and it is functionally fine, but it is a little dull.  I simply do not know all of the interesting tools out there to make a site more flashy, or rather the tools I have found don't work too well within the confines of the rules, in that all of the data needs to be onscreen at once and it must be highly visible.

Here is a screenshot of what I have worked out, as the site isn't public. Click on the screenshot to enlarge it.

[image: Screenshot]

This just barely fits the TV when the browser is full screen.

Anyone have any tips or ideas to make this look better?  Maybe something subtle that makes all the difference in a page like this?

Comment: This is not really on topic at SO. I would lose all the white texts in the cells since it is already explained to the left. Make the symbols bigger then

Answer (score 0):

You could give a slight demarcation between each cell in the table. Similar to he vertical gutter between the columns. This is because horizontally viewed, one might tend to get confused due to the amount of data in each cell.

*Provide a 4-5px space between each vertically adjoining cell*

Hope this was useful